# conflicts with LiquidCrystal.h and SoftwareSerial.h library?

Tags: library

Simply put, if I include and initialize both libraries, the LCD displays junk. If I don't include and use the software serial lib, the LCD displays correctly.

BTW, there are no devices physically connected to the software serial defined pins.....

Yes, I've verified that there are no pin definition conflicts.

The code is large (> 1200 lines, with multiple #ifdef statements for conditional target configurations) so I won't include it unless someone wants to see it.

So, does anyone know of a conflict with these 2 (current) libraries?

Comment: No, I can't think that there would be a conflict. It must be how you're using them.

Comment: I suggest making a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see if the problem exists without the rest of your code.

Comment: I simply commented out ALL the lines that setup or use the software serial, leaving all the other code intact, and the LCD then works fine.

Comment: The only thing the software serial does is read an hc-12 radio that's not even installed at this point.....

Comment: So make an MCVE that contains JUST lines for the LCD and the serial and see if it breaks.

Comment: The basic code wasn't the problem, but these statements were: radioSerial.print(F("AT+C001\r\n")); // set to channel 1

Comment: I 'borrowed' that code from some examples, not familiar with the code itself, will try something else.......

Comment: I removed the F( stuff from the code(not sure what it does) and the LCD works as expected......just what is that construct that I borrowed from the examples??

Comment: I found out what that construct does, and for the life of me I see no reason that it caused issues with the LCD.....my code doesn't use and special constructs or anything that would leave me to believe that there's a memory size issue......Now I can actually debug the code for serial communications for the radio module.